# Issues with facebook sdk for php login

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Hi I'm attempting to work with the Facebook sdk for php and I'm having some issues. The code below is copied directly from the example they supply yet I can not even get the html elements of the script to display...which makes me think there is a syntax error somewhere. When I examine the php that is embedded within the html section I believe I see some issues with the if - else statements. For instance, there seems to be a : when there should be a { in the following line:

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
```

Am I correct in saying this or does facebook use syntax I'm not familiar with?

```
<?php

 require 'facebook.php';

 // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'my_app',
   'secret' => 'my_secret',
 ));

 // Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();



 if ($user) {
 try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
<title>php-sdk</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3b5998;
  }
  h1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>php-sdk</h1>

<?php if ($user): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php else: ?>
  <div>
    Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>PHP Session</h3>
<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

<?php if ($user): ?>
  <h3>You</h3>
  <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

  <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
  <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
<?php else: ?>
  <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
<?php endif ?>

<h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
<?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a syntax error somewhere you should check your error_log. As for the PHP conditionals this is just an alternative syntax used to write them.

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php